# Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am using discord.js to make a discord bot. I keep getting the console error "Cannot read property 'startsWith' of undefined" how would I fix this??

Here is the code snippet

```
if(Discord.Message.content.startsWith('>ban')){
        if(Discord.Message.member.guild.me.hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS'))
        {
            if(Discord.Message.mentions.members.first()) 
            {
                Discord.Message.mentions.members.first.ban().then((member) => {
                    Discord.Message.channel.send("**BANNED** " + member.displayName + " has been banned:hammer:");
                }).catch(()=> {
                    Discord.Message.channel.send("You do not have permission to ban that user... If you think this is an issue, please contact a server administrator");
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try console logging Discord.Message. The error says Discord.Message does not have a field called content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you're in the *on message* event function.

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('>ban')) {
    // do your stuff
  }
})
```